# How to read firestore in text widgets and display them not in the list?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how can I read the firestore collection using text widgets, but not a list?

If I do as described in the manual, then my screen will simply be duplicated in as many values as there are documents in the collection. I searched the whole Internet, but I didn't find anything sensible on my topic. Maybe someone has encountered or uses something similar in their project?
To make it clearer, I want to fill the application with the values that I upload to the firestore. For example: I made a layout, and the values in the collection should be displayed in the necessary text widgets, in other words, the collection should be read in the usual way, and not by forming a list of values (as it would be convenient to display a shopping list, a list of users, but not in my case)

I tried everything possible, reread dozens of guides and the whole YouTube, but nothing helped, everywhere only the display in listview, listview, and I need to display the entire text. The application is in a sense a reference book, consists of the titles of articles and their contents, firestore for the convenience of replenishment.

My code:

```
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
        import 'package:get/get.dart';
        
        class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
        }
        
        class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {
          final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _test = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
              'users').where('nickname',isNull:false).snapshots();
        
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: SafeArea(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _test,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
        
                    return Container(
                      child: ListView(
                        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<
                              String,
                              dynamic>;
                          return Center(
                            child: Text(data['nickname']),
                          );
        
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
    
      }
    }
```

I am kindly requested to make corrections in my code, since I am a beginner and may not understand how and where to insert text fragments

Comment: Don't repost the same problem multiple times please. At best it'll just get closed again, but it may actually get you banned from the site. Your previous post was closed with feedback. If you address that feedback in that post, it becomes eligible for reopening.